# Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have telrik Q3 ( latest version) and after the abnormal shutdown i am continuously facing that error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

I also reinstall the telerik but problem is not resolved.
Any one please help me.

Comment: Is the correct version number referenced in your web.config?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The temp files that is created by IIS or the built-in Visual Studio development server might cause such problems. Close Visual Studio and try finding your project in one of these places and delete the folder:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

(Adjust according to the framework you use for the project)

As suggested by Chris Herring, also try deleting files inside this folder:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

You might also want to remove the website cache:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache
```

If that still does not solve the problem, deleting all temp files as suggested by Arun CM could be a final option:

```
%TEMP%
```

You can open these folders quickly by clicking the Start menu, pasting it in the search field (Win7, Vista) or through the Run option (XP), and hitting enter.

Comment: there is no folder in these places ... what i do now

Comment: I had to delete the files in this directory for a similar error C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: +1 - just had the same problem with Common.Logging. Sometime I really wish there was a button somewhere labeled "I am a dev, do not use any form of caching of temp file when I work".

Comment: Just clean the temp files... %temp% in run

Comment: An additional thing to take a look at is the licenses.licx if it exists in the root of your solution.

Comment: I tried all of these solutions with no luck. What ended up working for me was deleting all of the text in the licenses.licx file.